# How to add vSphere Client users with custom roles to a VM by Command?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm trying to automate the user creation process for VMs.

Currently I follow these steps manually on vSphere Client:

1. Click Inventory
2. Click Node
3. Click Local Users & Groups Tab
4. Right Click -> Add
5. Enter Login and Password
6. Choose "Users" Group and Click Add
7. Click OK
8. Click a VM
9. Click Permissions Tab
10. Right Click -> Add Permission
11. Click Add
12. Choose the user I created from list
13. Click Add
14. Choose Assigned Role "Customer" (I've created this role earlier.)
15. Click OK

I'd LOVE to automate this process by a command like:

addvmuser --login test --password test --group Users --role Customer --vmid 501

Preferably on SSH so I can code a script for it.

How to do it?

Oktay

Comment: Installing vSphere CLI sounds like a good start, I'll answer the question when I get a solution.

http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/vsphere_cli